# Interesting boardgames to play with children

Tags: recommendations

I have two children aged 8 and 6 and they like to play board games.  Some of the ones they have are for very young children and boring for an adult to play.  Are there any suggestions for games that they will understand and I can enjoy?

Comment: Should this kind of question be a community wiki? I don't think there is a single correct answer to the question.

Comment: @Simon Withers: That's no longer possible. See [Should the community wiki police be shut down?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down/7183#7183)

Comment: I would consider this question to be too open-ended and have voted to close. A way to save it might be to restrict what you're looking for more strongly: how many players, how long should it take, etc. See also this on meta: http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/66/recommend-a-game-questions

Comment: I think this is a perfectly fine question, and really don't see what the problem is with requests for recommendations.

Comment: Flagged for wiki conversion. See the meta article mentioned above.

Comment: I agree with Michiel - this is a perfectly good, specific question asking for good __board__ games to play with two children (i.e. __2 to 4 players__), __aged 6 to 8__ and __interesting for adults as well__ (the emphasised parts are what makes it specific). Let's not go all wiki-happy while we're still in Beta and everybody's trying to build a) rep, and b) a body of Q&As.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Legendary [Uno](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2223/uno). Its card game. Description from BGG:

> Players race to empty their hands and
>   catch opposing players with cards left
>   in theirs, which score points. In
>   turns, players attempt to play a card
>   by matching its color, number, or word
>   to the topmost card on the discard
>   pile. If unable to play, players draw
>   a card from the draw pile, and if
>   still unable to play, they pass their
>   turn. Wild and special cards spice
>   things up a bit.

Comment: The original (simplest & cheapest) Uno is best. Avoid randomising silliness like the electronic gizmo.

Comment: Uno shouldn't be even remotely interesting for an adult: there's no strategy, no tactics, and when you have the option to do one thing or another, very rarely you can actually choose in any meaningful way (just luck).

Comment: @Lo'oris, if there is no strategy or tactics then why some players wins more often than others? Personally I don't believe in luck :-)

Comment: @Pawka Some players win more often than others due to randomness. There is definitely some strategy in uno, but not enough to have a gigantic impact.

Comment: @CrazyJugglerDrummer I tend not to give all glory to randomness. Of course it makes big impact to the game (like randomness does in all card games). But for example when I play Uno with same company again and again, I can guess the moves what they are willing to do. Every person has its own playing style (me too), so there is where the strategy and tactics starts.

Comment: @Pawka: guess the moves *what*, "will he play the color or the number"? rofl, I can't believe I'm reading this.

Comment: @Lo'oris I'm not surprised that you can't find any tactics here :-D

Comment: @Lohoris. There are *definitely* different playing styles in Uno. The nasty cards have little impact at the beginning of the game, so some people prefer to hoard them till the end, when they can use them to better effect. This is risky, though, as another player may go out, leaving you with a bunch of high-point cards. On the other hand, having no nasty cards means you can't protect yourself when someone plays one on you. It's a question of balance, and different players have different strategies.

Answer (score 20):

[Ticket to ride](http://www.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/) is good balance to play with children and parents. Only from 8 though.

Comment: My 6 year old can play this game and actually requests to play it.

Answer (score 17):

Give [**Scotland Yard**](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/438/scotland-yard) a shot.

[image]

Scotland Yard a great game where one person is Mr. X, a fugitive from the law, and the other players team up as detectives.  Mr. X takes various modes of public transportation to move stealthily around the city of London, and it's up to the detectives to figure out where he is and capture him.

This is a great game of deduction and logical thinking, plus it's tons of fun.  It's fun for Mr. X, since there's something exciting about trying to escape from London's finest, and it's fun for the detectives since they get to work as a team to capture the slippery scofflaw.

This game won the prestigious [Spiel des Jahres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiel_des_Jahres) (Game of the Year) award in 1983, and I think it is a game that has aged quite well.

Comment: My 10-year-old loves this game but its difficult for younger kids. We started playing this when my son was around 8 so it should work.

Comment: I loved this game when introduced to it as a teenager, and even as an adult it holds its own. This is a game with staying power.

Comment: I loved this game when I was a kid. I can't remember how old I was, though.

Answer (score 16):

Blokus. My 6 and 10 year old equally love this game of fitting pieces on the board. As a parent I find its even more challenging to work with the stuff my 6 year old does and extend the game.

> Blokus encourages creative thinking
>   and has received a Mensa award for
>   promoting healthy brain activity. The
>   goal of this game is for players to
>   fit all of their pieces onto the
>   board. When placing a piece it may not
>   lie adjacent to the player's other
>   pieces, but must be placed touching at
>   least one corner of their pieces
>   already on the board. The player who
>   gets rid of all of their tiles first
>   is the winner and strategic thinking
>   helps as you block moves from your
>   opponent. Blokus sometimes comes to an
>   end because there are no more possible
>   moves.
>
> Four players make this abstract game
>   especially fast and exciting; however,
>   it can be just as fun for two or three
>   players. Blokus has come up with a
>   number of different ways to play the
>   game to make it more thrilling when
>   playing with less than four players.
>   Draft Blokus allows a player to use
>   more than one color and Reverse Blokus
>   reverses the entire game so that the
>   person who places the least amount of
>   tiles on the board is the winner. It
>   can even be played in a solitaire
>   version when one player attempts to
>   place all of their pieces in a single
>   sitting. A game of Blokus typically
>   lasts a 30 minutes. As a practical
>   feature, raised edges on the board
>   help keep the tiles in place and allow
>   convenient clean-up. This game
>   includes 84 pieces in four vibrant
>   colors, an instruction guide, and one
>   gameboard with 400 squares.

Answer (score 15):

[Mastermind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_%28board_game%29) - It's only playable by two people at a time (and one of them will have to be you), but my mom got it for me when I was about 7 or 8 and I *loved* it.

In fact, I still have it and even broke it out again the other night.  It's challenging, educational, and it's a game that makes kids *think*, but can be just as rewarding for adults.

Comment: I grew up playing this game, I don't know where it is now, though. Great game which can be played with pen and paper if you don't have it (or in a travel situation).

Answer (score 13):

[Carcassonne](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/822/carcassonne) is great with kids. Not too complicated, and they learn to divide their attention between long term and short term goals.

Comment: My 8 year old enjoys the map building components of Carc more than the game play. That said, she really, really enjoys the map building, which means we can have fun with less competitive challenges.

Comment: I agree; however, I recommend the use of the green box edition of the game (Hunters and Gatherers): the scoring systems are more straightforward; the tile art is more compelling; there's less in the way of rampant expansionism going on in the game, so it's generally cheaper (although you're not forced to get expansions for the blue box edition, either).

Answer (score 11):

I would recommend [Creationary](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/41833/creationary). Especially if the kids already enjoy LEGOs. The game works very similar to Pictionary, but instead of drawing an image for others to guess, you build it with LEGO pieces. The rules allow for a lot of flexibility and also promote the use of other LEGOs to be used to build your creations. It's very fun for adults, but I can imagine that children of 6 and 8 would also enjoy it.

Answer (score 9):

My 8 year old daughter has really enjoyed playing the Fluxx games.

Comment: We play Fluxx, its great fun.

Comment: I tricked my neighbor's son (in kindergarden) into doing more reading by bringing over Zombie Fluxx.  Now we just have to teach him better strategy, and to stop playing 'Hand Limit 0' when he was the one holding onto all of the 'Play (number)' cards.

Answer (score 9):

[Battleship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_%28game%29) is a ease to setup and play.

Comment: Yet another game which is completely luck-based apart from a few unintresting mandatory moves.

Answer (score 8):

[Tsuro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsuro) is simple and easy to follow.  It also plays fairly quickly and requires very minimal setup.  The game can play anywhere from 2-8 people, useful if you need a game to play with a group of kids.  While the suggested age is 8 and up, the users on BoardGameGeek have suggested it for 6 and up.

Comment: My 6 and 7 year old love Tsuro.

Answer (score 6):

The [Game of Life](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00000IWD7) could be good. Your kids should be able to follow what's going on in the game.

Comment: We have banned the Game of Life in our home. It's awful. You practically cut your own throat by going to college, you want as many kids as you can possibly get, etc.. Its chock full of outdated ideas and mores. It's possible that it could have gotten a pass on those problems if it had been any **fun** though.

Comment: It's not any fun whatsoever for adults, but I enjoyed it as a child.

Comment: That's true. I guess I only ever played it as a child.

Comment: When I see "Game of Life" I assume people are talking about Conway's version: http://sixfoottallrabbit.co.uk/gameoflife/

Comment: @TRiG, I know what you mean. In this instance (and based on user comments), maybe it would be more enjoyable to code that than  play this version. :-P

Comment: @kchau - TGoL is one of the first things I code when I learn a new language! It's always fun!

Answer (score 6):

**[Waterworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterworks_%28card_game%29)**

This game is very fun from 8 to 80 years old. It's like a domino game.

Answer (score 6):

[Set](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1198/set) should be a challenging game for all of you.

You lay out a number of cards with figures on them. The cards differ in the number, shape, color and shading of the figures on it. All players play concurrently trying to locate three cards where each attribute is either the same on all cards or different on all cards. The player who locates (and takes) the most sets wins.

Comment: This is a great one. My sister had her kids play this when she was teaching 3rd grade, and it is fun and challenging for adults as well.

Answer (score 6):

Some of my (7yo) son's and my favorites:

- **Go** : A 2-player strategy game with a built-in handicapping system. Within the first week or so, my little guy was able to hold his own with the greatest handicap applied to him, so it kept things fun for both of us.
- **Rummy** : A traditional card game played with a single deck.  While not intensive strategy-wise, there is enough there to keep it fun even for adults.  I may be biased: I grew up playing rummy with my brother and grandmother. :)
- **Chinese Checkers** : Everybody loves checkers, right?
- **Dominoes** : Like rummy, dominoes employs a balance of luck and strategy that gives everyone a chance to win (and a chance to lose) regardless of age.
- **Mancala** : Though only for two players, this is a fun strategy game that is simple to learn.
- **Scrabble** : In our house, younger players may play on a team with an older player, or get a limited number of poker chips or other counters at the beginning of each game which may later be traded for peeks at the dictionary for help choosing a word.
- **Clue** : Some strategy involved, and some luck.  Great for teaching deductive reasoning.
- **Operation** : Being grown-up doesn't make your hands any steadier!

Comment: Strategy? In Dominoes? Where, lol?

Comment: @Lo'oris: Sure there's strategy.  Limit your opponent's ability to place pieces by creating dead ends (segments too close to other segments to place anything on), and (if you are playing a variant that limits how many times a side can be played on) try to block in double-anything pieces so that other players cannot fork and increase the number of ends to play on.

Comment: +1 for the Go reference alone - I love the fact that it has a built in handicap.  I have a friend who has taught both of his kids to play Go.

Comment: Do you play 19x19 with him or 9x9 or another dimension?

Comment: @StuperUser We play 19x19.

Answer (score 4):

My personal favourite is [Zooloretto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zooloretto). As you would expect from Rio Grande Games, it has a great board, good pieces and good gameplay. It is also very easy to learn, and because it is based on a Zoo, it keeps the interest of the kids.

I have known kids of 7 and 8 playing this game, and in a few years time being introduced to the more adult games such as Agricola and Puerto Rico etc. It is easy enough for them to understand, but has enough variety to make it strategic enough for adults to play and enjoy.

According to [boardgamegeek](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/27588/zooloretto), its users recommend it for ages 6 and up, although the manufacturer says 8 and up. Most of the other games in the [Family Rank](http://boardgamegeek.com/familygames/browse/boardgame?sort=rank&rankobjecttype=family&rankobjectid=5499&rank=#40) are generally for kids of 8 and upwards.

Unfortunately, by daughter is only two, so I am still playing [Snail's Pace Race](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2767/snails-pace-race) with her.

Answer (score 3):

Here are four games that I would recommend for families:

For the 6 and under group:

- **[Piggyback Brigade](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1806/russelbande)** (Russelbande)

  - Circus pigs that race through the fields on their days off.
  - Easy to play, different every time and everyone can win (I mean, more than one person can win)
- **[Chuck-it Chicken](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/23656/chuck-it-chicken)** (Kiki Ricky)

  - A rooster is taking over the hen house, and it's up to you to stop him.
  - Basically a dice rolling game, get to the top first to win.

For the older than 6 group, we play:

- **[The Adventurers](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/43868/the-adventurers)**

  - Indiana Jones-style temple exploration.
  - Pretty fun, complete with rolling boulder. Often the winner is the only one who makes it out alive.  Often, there is no winner.... :)
- **[Robo Rally](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/18/roborally)**

  - Robot race in an ever changing factory.
  - A fun game, but this can run long.

Edit:  My son's 4th Birthday was last weekend and we got:

- **[The Ladybug Game](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/14076/the-ladybug-game)**

  - Lost Ladybugs have to travel home, meeting mantis and ants on the way.
  - Great game for kids.  Fun, no reading needed.
  - Simple to learn, easy to go from first to last then first place again.
  - Designed by a young girl.

Comment: I finally got to play Robo Rally a couple of weeks ago - absolutely +1 for kids! The game will keep the adults engaged but there's enough chaos happening in the factory (moving conveyors, lasers, holes in the floor, being pushed by other robots...) that less-than-optimal moves are pretty much assured for everyone, which means that kids have some slack in their decision-making.

Answer (score 3):

**[Ludo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludo_%28board_game%29)** is a race game that I played a lot in my early days. I missed it.

Answer (score 3):

I loved [Othello](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversi) as a child. And still do.

Answer (score 3):

I liked to play [Concentration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_%28game%29) with my parents when I was a kid. It's entertaining and doesn't have complicated rules -- you just need to use your memory!

Answer (score 2):

I love [Ubongo](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/16986/ubongo), even as an adult. Form tangram-like shapes, and collect shiny objects. What more do you want?

Answer (score 2):

We used to play [Shadows Over Camelot](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/15062/shadows-over-camelot) with my son and his friends when he was younger. The cooperative nature of the game meant that giving advice was OK and that the kids weren't pitted against adults.

We established a few house rules for kid games that allowed easier victories - the one I remember off the top of my head was that the first quest completed just disappeared instead of remaining on the table, flipped over, causing catapults or Saxons to appear.

I'll bet several of the current generation of cooperative games could be played this way with bright kids.

Answer (score 2):

My kids are now sixteen and eight.  They have been raised, steeped in board games.  The first "real" game that my son was able to play with adults was [Atilla](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/827).  And the first one my daughter got was [Settlers](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/13).  In both cases, they were in that same 6-8 age-range that you're talking about.  Those might be good ones to try for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have to admit I have not yet tried it but I have two children aged 6 at home and I just bought a copy of [The Alley Cats](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/16440/the-alley-cats-game) on ebay hoping it will be the game we can play with them.

Answer (score 1):

Senku/[Peg Solitaire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peg_solitaire) is a good game to players of every age.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a fourth player I can recommend [Dog](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2633/dog) as an awesome family game.

Similar to [Pachisi](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2136/pachisi) but you play in teams of 2 and instead of throwing dice you play cards. This adds teamplay and a lot of strategy to the game. One of our favorite games at home and among friends.

Answer (score 0):

Just saw a commercial for a game called [Hedbanz](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003AIM52A) on TV, looked like it could be fun. It's more of a card/party game. The gameplay is kind of like 20 Questions.

Answer (score 0):

**[Elkfest](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/403/elk-fest)**
Might be hard to come by and it's only two players but it's fun and it's fast. The purpose is to the help a wooden moose/elk to cross a river. You do this by flicking a wooden stepping stone close to where the elk is standing.

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to pick a "fun" game is fairly subjective, but I think a good answer is a game that has fairly simple mechanics along with a depth of strategy.  Also, when trying to play against your kids, you can assume that you would always do better given the same amount of time to think and strategize.  Also, I would interpret "fun" as "not having to dumb down your play too much to give your kid a chance to win."

> The best types of games for kids and adults are ones where there is more than one differing role to play in the game.  The adult can pick the role that has to do more with moderating the game.

2 games in this list fit that criteria.

**Scotland Yard**:

There is a Mr. X and everyone else.  The adult can play Mr. X while the kids work together to catch him.  It's possible to make sub-optimal moves fairly easily to give the kids a chance.

**Mastermind**:

One person attempts to discover a code, the other creates it.  It makes sense for the adult to pick codes based on the child level of understanding to make it easier or harder.

These games allow for a child not to have to compare their skill directly against yours.  For instance "solving" a single mastermind code says nothing about who is better at solving.  Running away in Scotland Yard is a different skill set that can't be compared directly with catching Mr. X.

**"Fixing Games"**:

If the game is such that everyone has the same goals, you can attempt to "meta" game somewhat.  For instance in Monopoly you could refuse to build improvements and attempt trades to even the others' chances.  Or in Risk you could purposely hole up in a single location and become a large army to beat as last challenge for the other players.  In this case, the "fun" is in attempting to keep a game balanced or just becoming a self enforced game mechanic the others have to overcome.  You're moving the game into an area where you have different goals than the kids.

Games of luck like Uno can be fun for them since you can't always beat them even if you try.  (But then there is really nothing redeeming in making people play a game with out real decisions where you can't improve over time.  Nobody learns anything.  Unless you really just need to waste time.)

Answer (score 0):

Wandering a bit away from "board game", you could try [Zombie Dice](http://www.sjgames.com/dice/zombiedice/) from Steve Jackson Games. Fun for the grownups, teaches counting and decision making (do I roll again? Am I winning?), and just random enough that you won't have to cheat to let the kids win. (My four-year-old is either way better or way luckier at this game than I am, for instance).

Answer (score -1):

[Snakes and Ladders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snakes_and_Ladders) is a very interesting game if you want to play with children .

Comment: It's a random, frustrating game if you ask me.

Comment: Its the most simplest and straight forward game that you can play w/o a strategy.